# Library not loaded: @rpath/libMatlabEngine.dylib

Tags: c++, matlab

I'm pretty much a novice when it comes to coding.
I'm trying to visualize a game in C++ using Matlab.
The makefile was partially given as part of the exercise.
I tried fixing the problem by using this: https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/custom-linking-to-required-api-libraries.html

The code works but when trying to implement the "GUI" this error comes up:

dyld[45987]: Library not loaded: @rpath/libMatlabEngine.dylib
Reason: tried: '/Applications/MATLAB_R2020a.app/bin/maci64/libMatlabEngine.dylib' (no such file), '/Applications/MATLAB_R2020a.app/sys/os/maci64/libMatlabEngine.dylib' (no such file), '/libMatlabEngine.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libMatlabEngine.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libMatlabEngine.dylib' (no such file)

```
MATLAB_ROOT=/Applications/MATLAB_R2020a.app
Gpp=g++
LD=g++
CPPFLAGS=-MMD -MP -std=c++11 -Wpedantic \
         -I ${MATLAB_ROOT}/extern/include/ -pthread
LDFLAGS=-L ${MATLAB_ROOT}/extern/bin/maci64/ -pthread
LDLIBS=-lMatlabDataArray -lMatlabEngine
srcs = $(wildcard *.cpp)
objs = $(srcs:.cpp=.o)
deps = $(srcs:.cpp=.d)
targets = viergewinnt
default: viergewinnt
run: viergewinnt
    LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\
    ${MATLAB_ROOT}extern/bin/maci64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} \
        ./viergewinnt
viergewinnt: viergewinnt.o cviergewinnt.o cviergewinntGUI.o
    $(LD) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)
%.o: %.cpp
    $(Gpp)  $(CPPFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
.PHONY: clean
clean:
    $(RM) $(targets) $(objs) $(deps) *~
-include $(deps)
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.